# How to acquire all the permits in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to create a Bounded Queue using Semaphores and I need to acquire all the permits for a semaphore.

Is there any method in Java to do this?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire(int)

Comment: @ShireResident, actually, the drainPermits() method might be better suited.

Comment: @jameslarge. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling [`acquire(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire-int-) will block until specified number of permits are acquired.

Calling [`drainPermits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#drainPermits--) will acquire any permits that are currently available and return immediately.

The notion of acquiring "all permits for a semaphore" doesn't really make sense. A `Semaphore` is created with an initial number of free permits, but you can `release()` additional permits and then `acquire()` them. So your application should track the number of permits that it wishes to allocate, and carefully coordinate `acquire()` and `release()` calls to ensure that number is not changed.